# What was the state of the Congo in 1959?

Tags: religion, colonization, religious-history, belgium, congo

I'm reading the [Poisonwood Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Poisonwood_Bible). It is about a missionary family, the Prices, who in 1959 move from the U.S. state of Georgia to the village of Kilanga in the Belgian Congo.

I really have no idea what was going on with respect to the history of this period and the relationship between Belgium and the Congo and American missionaries.

Does anyone have a brief outline, I mean the book explains a bit but I really want to read it whilst knowing political backdrop.

Comment: Gotta admit, there's no one simple link I could find in WP that would answer this succinctly.

Comment: This is rather broad in my view? Don't know what 'the book explains', and don't know whether your own research has given you much more than eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgian_Congo#Toward_independence Please clarify further, eg whether specifics from the book ("what's going on") might need explanation?

Comment: You may find *[The Missions and Political Development in the Congo](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1158884)* to be of some use but, as LangLangC already commented, some details as to what you are looking for would help.